# Unblock Myself on Gtalk

Tags: google-talk

If I have been blocked by a buddy on Gtalk, is it possible for me to unblock myself and appear online to my buddy who blocked me?

Comment: If someone blocked you, they probably blocked you for a reason, right?

Comment: Friends don't block friends on Gtalk.

Answer (score 7):

No.

You can't. I mean, why block someone if that someone can unblock him/herself?

Actually, though, the answer is yes. Go talk to your friend, and make conciliations.

Comment: This might involve using a land line phone, or sending him/her a letter in the mail.

Comment: Or digging up an old bike or pair of shoes, and going on a journey into the wilderness outside.

Comment: Imagine that eh? Old 20th century things.

Comment: Give him a hug, maybe a kiss (if you want to gay it up)... But be gentle...